# PAE kernel with 32bit OS

Tags: pae

We have procured Dell Blade M620 with 128GbRAM and Dell Rack R820 with 128GB Ram servers. Now on this I am required to install i386 12.04 Server, as the application what we have runs on 32Bit OS only. Can I install 32Bit 12.04 with PAE kernel on the hardware.

Regards

Kanak

Answer (score 0):

First, try to understand, what is really needed for your app - 32-bit kernel or 32-bit libs?

32-bit libs+utils can by normally deployed on *any* modern 64-bit Linux using LXC technology (more advanced) or even Debootstrap (more stupid):

```
apt-get install debootstrap
mkdir -p /home/chroot/First
debootstrap --arch=i386 precise /home/chroot/First http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/
mount --bind /dev  /home/chroot/First/dev
mount --bind /proc /home/chroot/First/proc
mount --bind /sys  /home/chroot/First/sys

mount --bind /opt/myapp/ /home/chroot/First/opt/myapp/
chroot /home/chroot/First
    /opt/myapp/bin/myapp
```

If you want the more polished solution, then LXC can be configured in 5 minutes using https://code.google.com/p/lxc-loader/wiki/QuickStart article.

But if your app is so strange that requires 32-bit **kernel**...

```
apt-get install linux-image-generic-pae
```